# Соответствие полей в Entity и в liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

Изучаю учебный проект - работа с базами данных. Вроде как заявлено, что он рабочий. Поднять полностью проект еще не получилось.
Вот класс описание сущности.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventories", schema = "inventories")
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "part_num_oem")
    private String partNumOEM;
    @Column(name = "part_num")
    private String partNum;
    @Column(name = "part_name")
    private String partName;
    private String version;
    private Integer year;
    @Column(name = "image_exists")
    private Boolean imageExists;
}
```

А вот файл liquibase создания самой таблицы

```
<changeSet id="create_inventories" author="adam">
    <createTable tableName="inventories" schemaName="inventories">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="part_num_oem" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        <column name="part_num" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        <column name="part_name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="version" type="VARCHAR(50)"/>
        <column name="year" type="INT"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

В этом фале нет поля *image_exists* из класса описания Entity.
Разве это не является ошибкой?
Или так можно делать?
При добавлении новой сущность в базу в этом случае не выскочит ошибка?

Разве файл сущности Entity не должен полностью соответствовать файлу для liquibase?

Comment: Вы уверены, что больше нет миграций, которые изменяют таблицу? Разработка могла вестись итерационно и в какой-то начальной версии поля не было, а потом добавили.

Comment: по-моему при старте liquibase создаст таблицу, а далее при старте приложения оно упадет, т.к. Hibernate выдаст ошибку про отсутствие image_exists

Answer (score 0):

> все будет зависеть от способа од того как вы захотите добавлять данные
> в базу данных, например: у вас есть репозиторий  для вашего Entity

```
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory ,Long> {

}
```

и вы делаете например

```
inventoryRepository.save(new Inventory());
```

то я предположу что будет ошибка,  Unknown column imageExists  in 'field list'

но если например написать

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "INSERT INTO  inventory (partNum) VALUES 
('someValue');")
void insertInventory();
```

то ошибки быть не должно, то есть разница только в том кто будет формировать
запросы к таблице, а  liquibase в вашем случае выступает в роли ddl и не больше того

Comment: Я с вами согласен, но меня в принципе интересовало - возможно ли возникновение ошибки или в этом коде все правильно. Тот вариант, что вы предложили, согласен будет работать, но завтра кто-то подключится к проекту новый, кто об этом не знает и добавит запись в базу, как показано у вас в первом примере и получит ошибку и будет сильно удивлен. Т.е. я так понимаю, что в идеале должно быть приведено в соотвествие.

Comment: @alex дело в том, что ваш проект архитектурно строится на JPA отношениях, в первую очередь это сделано что бы упростить вам роботу с БД, а возможность использования nativeQuery, никак этому не мешает, JPA переносит мышления разработчика ближе к обьектной структуре роботы с БД, но иногда нужно сделать простой Query, зависит от ситуации и требованию